# Dynamic Branching/Plumbling

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to use Dynamic Branching/Plumbing in a snakefile?

I wish to perform the following:

```
A -> B -> D
or
A -> C -> D
```

Depending on whether a config variable is true.

for example:

```
*(rules.B if config["deblur"] == True else rules.B),
```

In this instance it runs both rules B and C.

I have tried

```
if config["deblur"] == True:
    rules.B,
else:
    rules.C,
```

But this gives me a syntax error.

In the next rule the input is as follows.

```
    input:
        qiime_feature_table_input = rules.qiime_deblur.output.qiime_deblur_table if config["deblur"] == "True" else rules.qiime_denoise.output.qiime_denoise_table
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value of the configuration variable is known before runtime, there's no need for dynamic modification of the DAG in this case. Here's a simple snakefile that will run rules `a -> b -> d` if `config_var` is true and rules `a -> c -> d` if `config_var` is false:

```
config_var = True

rule all:
    input:
        "d/out.txt",

rule a:
    output:
        "a/a.txt",
    shell:
        """
        echo 'a' > '{output}'
        """

rule b:
    input:
        rules.a.output,
    output:
        "b/b.txt",
    shell:
        """
        echo 'b' > '{output}'
        """

rule c:
    input:
        rules.a.output,
    output:
        "c/c.txt",
    shell:
        """
        echo 'c' > '{output}'
        """

rule d:
    input:
        rules.b.output if config_var else rules.c.output,
    output:
        "d/out.txt",
    shell:
        """
        cat '{input}' > '{output}'
        """
```

Comment: This looks much cleaner than my approach.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thank you!  I was actually doing this but I had an error later the workflow where I had the config variable in brackets which negated ==.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies to your case, but one option could be to have these two rules produce the same file (it could be a dummy file), but define only one rule at a time with a conditional. Here's a rough pseudocode:

```py
config_var = True

rule all:
    input: 'test.txt'

if config_var:
    rule B:
         output: 'test.txt'
else:
    rule C:
         output: 'test.txt'
```